# How to prevent my gridview from creating additional rows in c#?

Tags: c#, mysql, gridview

I try researching this everywhere but it appears when I run my windows form application and display my database. Each it keeps automatically skipping and adding rows.
Here is a screen shot of my gridview
[image]

Here is also my code where it displays the database when I click a button:

```
    try
    {
        conn = new MySqlConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = connstring;

        query = "INSERT INTO schedule(name) VALUES(@namevalue)";
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@namevalue", this.nameEmp.Text);

        conn.Open();

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


        MessageBox.Show("Connection Success");
        myadapt = new MySqlDataAdapter();
        string sq = "SELECT * FROM schedule";
        myadapt.SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand(sq, conn);
        tb = new DataTable();
        myadapt.Fill(tb);

        BindingSource src = new BindingSource();
        src.DataSource = tb;

        dataGridView1.DataSource = src;

    }
    catch (MySqlException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: I would assume from your code above that it keeps inserting whatever the value is on `this.nameEmp.Text` before selecting from table `schedule` hence automatically adding and skipping rows.

Comment: what do you mean prevent creating additional rows?

Comment: yes. it should't do that right? I didn't do that before.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean you want to show those rows which name column is not empty?
Gridview can just show the table you query from the DB,so you can change the SQL code to get the right table,
for example:change `SELECT * FROM schedule`  to  `SELECT * FROM schedule WHERE schedule(name) IS NOT NULL`.

Comment: well when I first made the program, It worked fine. I only showed just the first 8 entries. but I added some code and each time I would display the table, it would show something like

name 1
name 2 
name 3
blank 30

Answer (score 0):

actually, I figured it out. I had in that code above the statement
INSERT twice in my program. I removed it and redid my database on my server and fixed the problem. So sorry for the trouble.